# The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration - Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Olá,

Eu tento acessar o meu phpMyAdmin porém aparece o erro:
`The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.`

Alguém que sabe resolver isso?

Comment: Qual a versão do *PHP* instalada?

Comment: No PHP info diz ser: "5.6.32-1", uso o Ubuntu 14.04 32 bits.

Comment: Tenta procurar o package no repositório do Ubuntu digitando os comandos no Terminal:

`sudo apt-get update` e `sudo apt search mbstring`

Veja se encontra alguma coisa.

Comment: Resultou nisto: https://pastebin.com/NUCHLCTc

Comment: O `php-mbstring` está constando como instalado. Verifique se o `mbstring` está configurado no PHP corretamente usando o comando: `php -m`. Deverá aparecer `mbstring` na listagem.

Comment: Bom, o comando `php` está mostrando o erro:
`php: symbol lookup error: php: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_exec`

Comment: Parece que você está com a versão 7 do *PHP* instalada também, certo? Pode estar dando algum conflito entre as duas versões. Você também pode tentar isso: https://askubuntu.com/a/925161

Comment: O comando apt-get que estava no link que você forneceu resolveu. Obrigado.